# How to display highlighted sprite

Tags: html, css

I don't really know how to explain this, so I drew a picture:

[image]

I want the initial look of the page to look like the right envelope, but when you hover over each piece of the envelope it highlights and describes the envelope and if you click on it then you will be redirected to a page about the envelope

this is what I have tried to do

If you can explain how to do this through html and css please help!

Comment: "If you can explain how to do this through html and css please help!" That's not how it works. You should come to SO with a specific question in mind (e.g. "I have this code, and have tried this and that, but it doesn't work"), not with the expectation that we write HTML and CSS from the *groundup* for you.

Comment: @Terry, that's why we can just give a one-sentence answer so at least the asker knows what they need to go learn.

Comment: A one-sentence answer is rarely a constructive or helpful answer, and often one that is of low quality. That would belong to a **comment**, and not an answer.

Comment: @Terry, one sentence can sometimes (not rarely) be extremely effective in pointing someone in the right direction. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have both images, you'll add a javascript handler on hover (you can use jquery) which changes the first image into the second when the mouse is over it. And of course the div surrounding is a link to the desired page.

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought that Javascript would have to be included.. Do you know of any pre-made scripts that I can use to get learning the javascript part out of the way?

Comment: Edit: Thanks for the help once again, Since this reply I have been learning Javascript through w3schools, and I know I need to use Javascript events. I'm glad you helped steer me in the right direction!